# Multiline matching: extract separate lines

Tags: sed, multiline, slurm

I have command output like

```
var="""
Name=<Some name>
    key1=value1
    key2=value2 key3=value3
    key4=value4

Name=<Some other name>
    key1=val1
    key2=val2 key3=val3
    key4=val4

"""
```

See e.g. the output of `scontrol show partition`.

From these multiline strings, how do I extract a certain key value pair?

I can e.g. use `sed` to match a block via

```bash
echo "${var}" | | sed -n '/^Name=/,/^\s+key4=/p'
```

This gives me the entire block (nothing is gained here)

How do I get output like

```
<Some name>: key4=value4
<Some other name>: key4=val4
```

or

```
<Some name>: key3=value3
<Some other name>: key3=val3
```

EDIT in response to comments

i.e. print the Name of the block together with the value of the specified key.

Moreover one can assume:

- Key and value are separated by `=`
- Key value pairs are separated by
- Keys or values do not contain white spaces or new lines
- Keys do not appear in values

Comment: `|  perl -00ne 'print"$1: $2\n" if /^Name=(.*)(?s:.)*^\s+key4=(.*)/m'` if you don't mind using perl

Comment: Use, `scontrol --json` and use `jq`. Human output is for humans. Machine output is for machines.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, thanks, no I don't mind. Can you please generalize the regexp a bit. I.e. to allow just typing the key regardless if it is after the `\s+` or behind some other key value pairs. Then I am willing to accept if formulated as an answer.

Comment: @KamilCuk unfortunately my `scontrol` version doesn't have this option yet.

Comment: What about `scontrol -o`?

Comment: @Stefan, i've added more details in an anwser

Comment: @Stefan, if it doesn't work, could you explain or give an example of what you expect, the `\s+` part was taken from the question

Comment: Are you missing a newline in `key2=val2 key3=val3`? Now it looks like, that the value of key2 equals `val2 key3=val3`.

Comment: The right answer will depend on what you haven't told us yet which is - what can those "value"s be? Can they contain spaces? Can they contain newlines? Can they contain the names of other keys? Can they be null? If they can contain spaces, does the field get quoted? If single or double quotes? If double quotes how do you escape a double quote inside the quoted string? etc., etc. Don't assume we know what `scontrol show partition` output looks like.

Comment: @WalterA key value pairs are separated by whitespaces. See my updated question.

Comment: @EdMorton I updated my question in response to your comment.

Comment: @KamilCuk indeed the `-o` option is available, which makes the output way easier to parse. My question however is more general and not about parsing the specific `scontrol` output. But thanks for pointing out this option. It is certainly helpful!

Comment: Hi! And my point is that many times command line tools have a machine-readable format that makes parsing simpler, like `btrfs --format json` `journalctl -o json` `findmnt --json` `docker ps --format json`. Before writing a parser, check the options.

Answer (score 2):

Some explanations about the comment, how it works

```
perl -00ne 'print"$1: $2\n" if /^Name=(.*)(?s:.)*^\s+key4=(.*)/m'
```

From command line help `perl -h`

```
-0[octal]         specify record separator (\0, if no argument)
```

here 0 special case "paragraph mode" (Two or more consecutive newline characters will act as the record separator).

```
-n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
-e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

About the expression, the if modifier is shorter one-line in this case but, is the same as

```
if (/^Name=(.*)(?s:.)*^\s+key4=(.*)/m) {
   print "$1: $2\n";
}
```

About the regex the capturing groups `(.*)` are matching any character except newline `.`
The `s` flag inside non-capturing group `(?s:`..`)` changes the meaning of `.` to also match newline.
The `m` flag to allow `^` to match also the position after a newline.

About backtracking, because of the multiple `*` quantifiers, the regular expression may have a catastrophic backtracking, some more quantifiers to prevent backtracking, the regex can be improved:

```
/^Name=(.*+)(?:.*+\n)*?\s+key4=(.*+)/
```

`(?:`..`)` : non-capturing group

Answer (score 0):

I would choose for the solution

```
echo "${var}" | grep -Eo "^Name=.*| key4=.*" | paste -d ':' - -
```

When you look for a `sed` solution, you will also need the additional `paste` command:

```
echo "${var}" | sed -rn 's/^Name=//p; s/^\s+(key4=)/\1/p' | paste -d ' ' - -
```

With the given input, `awk` can handle it without the help of `paste`:

```
echo "${var}" | awk -F= -v lookup="key4" '
  /^Name=/ {printf("%s: ", $2)}
  $1 ~ lookup {print lookup "=" $2}
  '
```

This will fail when the value of key4 has an `=` inside, the value will be truncated.
Fix this using the `sub()` function and remove the first part of the line.

```
echo "${var}" | awk -v lookup="key4=" '
  /^Name=/ {sub(/[^=]*=/,""); printf("%s: ", $0)}
  $1 ~ lookup {sub(/ */,""); print}
  '
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk, this will produce the output you asked for from the input you provided:

```
$ echo "$var" |
awk -v OFS=': ' 'sub(/^Name=/,""){name=$0} sub(/.*key4=/,""){print name, $1}'
<Some name>: value4
<Some other name>: val4
```

```
$ echo "$var" |
awk -v OFS=': ' 'sub(/^Name=/,""){name=$0} sub(/.*key3=/,""){print name, $1}'
<Some name>: value3
<Some other name>: val3
```

and it'll even work for `key2` which your other answers so far won't work for since `key3` appears after it on the same line:

```
$ echo "$var" |
awk -v OFS=': ' 'sub(/^Name=/,""){name=$0} sub(/.*key2=/,""){print name, $1}'
<Some name>: value2
<Some other name>: val2
```

but, like every other answer you have so far, there are many possible inputs that it won't work for. You'd have to provide more details about your input format and sample input/output that covers all cases to get a robust solution that works for all cases but, for example, here's a far more robust script using any POSIX awk that can handle:

- the target key being a substring of some other key
- the target value containing any white space, even newlines (but not an empty line mid-string)
- the target value containing escaped (by doubling) double
  quotes

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var='
Name="Some name"
    key1=value1
    key2="some value2" key3=value3
    dummykey4="fake4"
    key4="A value4 that has
        a newline in it"

Name="Some other name"
    key1=val1
    key2=val2 key3="some ""big"" val3"
    key4=val4

'

for tgt in key2 key3 key4; do
    echo "===== $tgt ====="
    echo "$var" |
    awk -v RS= -v tgt="$tgt" '
        {
            tail = $0
            while ( match(tail,/[^[:space:]=]+=([^[:space:]]+|("[^"]*"|"")+)/) ) {
                key_val = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                sep = index(key_val,"=")
                key = substr(key_val,1,sep-1)
                val = substr(key_val,sep+1)
                k2v[key] = val
                tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            }
            print k2v["Name"], k2v[tgt]
        }
    '
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
===== key2 =====
"Some name" "some value2"
"Some other name" val2
===== key3 =====
"Some name" value3
"Some other name" "some ""big"" val3"
===== key4 =====
"Some name" "A value4 that has
        a newline in it"
"Some other name" val4
```

but whether that's overkill or not robust enough or making wrong assumptions, I don't know.

Note that with that second approach of creating an array of values indexed by keys you can do far more than just print values, you can compare them reorder them, or do anything else you want with them, e.g. you could write:

```
if ( k2v["Name"] == "John Smith") && (k2v["key2"] > k2v["key3"]) ) {
    print k2v["key4"], k2v["key1"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/^Name=(.*)/\1:/;T;h
         :a;n;s/^$//;s/.*(key4=\S+).*/ \1/;Ta;H;x;s/\n(.+)/\1/p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing (`-n`) and on easier regexp (`-E`).

Store the name following `Name=` in the hold space.

Then fetch the next line until an empty line or a line containing the required variable (in this case `key4`), append it to the hold space, swap to the hold space remove the introduced newline and print the result.

N.B. This relies on the variable following the variable name to contain no white space. If no variable name is found, nothing is printed.